# Select query inside an update query

Tags: mysql, select, sql-update

I have two database table namely readings and archive.
How can I update the jan column name in archive table based on the records of the prevRead column in the readings table. Here is my query:

```
 $sql_query = "SELECT prevRead FROM readings ";
 $result_set=mysql_query($sql_query);
 while($row=mysql_fetch_row($result_set))
 {
    $sql = "UPDATE archive SET jan = '$row[0]'";
    mysql_query($sql);
 }
```

For example I have records of 500 and 200 in the prevRead column of readings table then I did the query. The output in the jan column of the archive table would be 200 and 200. How can I make the output 500 and 200.

Comment: You have to have a Foreign Key For example: `reading_id` in your `archive` table... Do you have one? So that you can relate tables to one another.

Comment: Don't have. And I'd like query that don't use join tables if possible

Comment: If you don't have foreign key in archive table then how would you know for which jan entry in the reading table will mirror to which entry of the archive table?

Comment: Yeah too bad, I'm only using free hosting with no foreign key in their database. I just want to copy the prevRead entries into jan entry, isn't that possible? Newbie here.

Comment: In any free hosting they will give you the liberty to manage your database any way you want. If they don't then I can recommend some of the best free php-mysql-phpmyadmin-ftp hosting if you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, add a foreign key column/field in `archive` table. Ex: `reading_id`.

This `reading_id` will hold the same value of primary key in the table `readings`. In this way you will know which entry of `readings` relates to which entry of `archive`.

Then you just have to modify the code this way:
(I am assuming that the primary key of your `readings` table is `id`)

```
$sql_query = "SELECT id, prevRead FROM readings";
$result_set = mysql_query($sql_query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_set))
{
    $sql = "UPDATE archive SET jan = '". $row['prevRead'] ."' WHERE reading_id = '". $row['id'] ."'";
    mysql_query($sql);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. The result I wanted was already been outputted with the help of your code.